# How do I test if an object exists in a Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've seen other questions, and I've tried the filter function, but I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly.

Essentially I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[{"hour":"6 am", "date":"2012-12-01"},{"hour":"7 am", "date":"2012-12-01"}]
```

I'm looping through a set period of days, and on each day I'm looping through the hours between 6am and 9pm. If the hour(as in the hour on that specific date) exists in the above array. I want to mark it as available in a new object that I then pass to a new array. Below is the code I'm currently using.

```
for(var i = 0; i < dayCount; i++){//Loop through the days that exist in the schedule
    day = new Object();
    day.date = Date.parse(startDate).add(i).days();
    day.dayName = weekday[day.date.getDay()]
    day.hours = new Array();
    for(var j = 6; j < 22; j++){ //Loop through hours of the day seeing if they're available/scheduled, etc.
        if(j<=12){
            thisHour = j +' am';
        } else{
            thisHour = j-12 + ' pm';        
        }
        var thisIsAvailable = $(assignedHours).filter(function(){
                return assignedHours.hour == thisHour && assignedHours.date == day.date.toString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            });
        var thisIsScheduled = 0;
        day.hours.push({hour: thisHour,available: thisIsAvailable, scheduled: thisIsScheduled});
    }
daysInSchedule.push(day);
}
```

A couple notes. I use .toString() on the day.date property because it is formatted in JS Date format and the value I'm comparing it against is in the MYSQL Date format. I've alerted (talk about old school debugging) thisIsAvailable.length, and I get 0 everytime. Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Just realized I forgot to tell you all something very important. The array I give you is contained in the variable Named assignedHours. Sorry about leaving that out.

EDIT 2: To clarify, my question is in the bit between the two code excerpts. I'm trying to see if one of the objects in the given array matches the day and hour in the loop, and nested loop I'm running through. If it does I want to pass that on to a new object which I then push into the hours array of the day. If not then I still pass the object but with a 0 value for it being available.

Comment: I don’t see a question here. What is the output? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Try alerting the outcome of each of the parts that create `thisIsAvailable` to see exactly what is returned from the methods in your filter method, that will explain why you are getting 0.

Comment: Your filter does not work like that. Rewrite it with a native loop and it will work (or use [`Array`s `filter` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)) - don't use jQuery on arrays

Comment: @Bergi It does work that way assuming assignedHours is an array with objects. http://jsfiddle.net/Feqn5/ though he needs `this.hour` rather than `assignedHours.hour`

Comment: @Bergi I know it's not working, but could you explain why? Maybe as an answer.

Comment: @canon make that an answer because it worked. You sir/madam are beautiful.

Comment: @FrankB: Have a look at x3ro's answer. However, it is recommended not use jQuery for such things, as it will return jQuery's DOM wrapper thing instead of an object

Comment: @canon I'm going to accept his answer because it's more comprehensive, but I wanted you to get at least a bit of reputation for solving my problem so quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that your problem lies in the way you are using jQuery's `filter` method:

```
var thisIsAvailable = $(assignedHours).filter(function(){
    return assignedHours.hour == thisHour && assignedHours.date == day.date.toString("yyyy-MM-dd");
});
```

If I'm not mistaken, `assignedHours.hour` will always be undefined because it always references your `assignedHours` array (where you'd want it to reference the current element you are filtering, i.e. an element *inside* `assignedHours`).

You'll probably want to do something like this:

```
var thisIsAvailable = $(assignedHours).filter(function(array_key){
    return this.hour == thisHour && this.date == day.date.toString("yyyy-MM-dd");
});
```

---

**Edit1:** As pointed out by @Kevin B, `$.grep` is better suited for filtering arrays as it does not create a DOM wrapper around your array:

```
$.grep(assignedHours, function(el) {
    return el.hour == thisHour && el.date == day.date.toString("yyyy-MM-dd");
});
```

Comment: +1 A more appropriate method (in my opinion) is `$.grep()` rather than `$(arr).filter()`, though filter does get the job done.

Comment: +1 to @KevinB. `$.fn.filter` returns an ugly jQuery DOM wrapper instance, not an array as you might have expected

Comment: I don't really need the wrapper or the array, just the knowledge that it exists. It's dirty I'm sure, but right now I'm under a deadline to get it working, then after that I'm going to be given the privilege of cleaning it up.

Answer (score 2):

Promoted from a comment to an answer at the OP's request:

> You should be checking `this.hour` and `this.date` in your filter function.